# How hard is it to modify the Django Models?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, geodjango

I am doing geolocation, and Django does not have a PointField. So, I am forced to writing in RAW SQL.  GeoDjango, the Django library, does not support the following query for MYSQL databases (can someone verify that for me?)

```
 cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM l_tag WHERE\
               (GLength(LineStringFromWKB(LineString(asbinary(utm),asbinary(PointFromWKB(point(%s, %s)))))) < %s + accuracy + %s)\
```

I don't nkow why GeoDjango library cannot do this in MYSQL database.  I hate writing RAW SQL for calculating distances between two points.  Is there a way I can create my own library for Django that can handle this? If so, how hard is it?

Comment: Which version are you using? In Django 1.2 there is a new method to execute raw SQL.

Comment: I'm using 1.0, But 1.2 is not stable?

Comment: Well the goal is to release 1.2 at 12. April: http://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2010/mar/23/django-1_2-release-schedule-update-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just extend a class that's already there?  Just curious and wish I could help you specifically.

Comment: Something like this maybe: http://wolfram.kriesing.de/blog/index.php/2007/extend-djangos-user-class

Answer (score 0):

GeoDjango does have a PointField.

It looks like you're trying to do a dwithin field lookup, which does not work on MySQL (as of April 2010), but does in Postgres:

class Tag(Model):
   point = PointField()

Tag.objects.filter(point__dwithin=(point,D(mi=4)))

Careful with this kind of query, as it requires a table scan.  If you can tolerate selecting all points within a rectangular region, you could use the bounding box contained query:

Tag.objects.filter(point__contained=geom)

where geom is a polygon.